# Add some cocoapods will cause Xcode preview into build loop since Xcode 14.3

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, xcode14, xcode14.3

Currently my sample project uses these Pods:

```
pod(name = "SQLCipher", version = "4.5.4", linkOnly = true)
listOf(
    "FirebaseInstallations",
    "FirebaseStorage",
    "FirebaseRemoteConfig",
    "Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport",
    "FirebaseAppCheck",
    "FirebaseCrashlytics",
    "FirebaseMessaging",
).forEach {
    pod(name = it, version = "10.9.0")
}
```

Preview works in Xcode 14.2 and before, but preview will into build loop since 14.3.
Any idea to dig this issue?

Comment: The problem is investigating by kotlin team. 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-58800